# What are the three Terumots?

Tags: yirmiyahu--book-of, teruma

In [Yirmiyahu 2:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15999#v=3) there is a Mahari Kra that attempts to explain what the words "Reshit Tebu'ato" ("רֵאשִׁית תְּבוּאָתֹה") are regarding. One of the things he mentions were the three terumot. What are these terumot?

Comment: Hey Neil, welcome to Mi Yodeya! This is an interesting question.... [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9691/5323) might help you, although AFAICT it only has two terumot -- *terumah gedolah* and *terumat maaser*; though there is still the possibility that one of the other things mentioned there is called "terumah" in a different context. I hope to see you around!

Comment: I don't know about 3, but the "5 Terumot" so-to-speak are found in [Bava Metzia 4:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%93_%D7%97)

Answer (score 1):

The *Mahari Kara* also says all three *t'rumos* are called "*reshis*". I think they're probably

- *t'ruma g'dola* (called "*reshis*" in [*Bamidbar* 18:12](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9946#showrashi=true&v=12) and [*D'varim* 18:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9982#showrashi=true&v=4)),
- *t'rumas maaser* (never explicitly called "*reshis*" that I know of, but it's called "*t'ruma*" in [*Bamidbar* 18:26](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9946#showrashi=true&v=26) and compared to *t'ruma g'dola* in [*Bamidbar* 18:27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9946#showrashi=true&v=27)), and
- *chala* (called "*reshis*" and "*t'ruma*" in [*Bamidbar* 15:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9943#showrashi=true&v=20)).

Comment: Note that bikkurim is also called reishit.

Comment: @ShimonbM I know, but the _Mahari Kara_ lists it separately from the three _t'rumos_.

Comment: Is bikkurim called "*trumah*" also? ( @ShimonbM )

Comment: @Shokhet - Short answer is yes: Devarim 12:17 mentions תרומת ידך, which is explained in Sifrei Devarim as a reference to Bikkurim (see Rashi, who quotes the midrash). See also Makkot 17a ("ותרומת ידך אלו בכורים") and the commentaries on Terumot 3:7,  Maaser Sheni 5:6 and Bikkurim 2:1 (amongst other places).