# IF many poor people ask at once, must one give tzedaka to each one

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity

The Sefer Hamitzvot (chafetz chaim) writes:

> "whoever sees a poor person asking [for tzedaka] and ignores him and
>   does not give him tzedaka - he transgresses this biblical
>   commandment..."

what happens in a case when many poor people are coming to ask.

for example, sometimes on the street in a religious neighborhood, or in a synagogue, etc. one is approached by many poor people. must one give something to each one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving charity to someone about whom the giver knows nothing?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/giving-charity-to-someone-about-whom-the-giver-knows-nothing)

Comment: @Fred edited...

Answer (score 2):

See the Shulchan Aruch  (יו"ד רנא -  ט):

> .היו לפניו עניים הרבה ואין בכיס לפרנס או לכסות או לפדות את כולם מקדים
>   הכהן ללוי והלוי לישראל והישראל לחלל והחלל לשתוקי והשתוקי לאסופי
>   והאסופי לממזר והממזר לנתין והנתין לגר והגר לעבד משוחרר במה דברים
>   אמורים בזמן שהם שוים בחכמה אבל אם היה ממזר ת"ח וכ"ג עם הארץ ממזר תלמיד
>   חכם קודם (ואפילו חכם לכסות ועם הארץ להחיות ואשת חבר כחבר) (ב"י
>   מהירושלמי) וכל הגדול בחכמה קודם לחבירו ואם היה אחד מהם רבו או אביו
>   אע"פ שיש שם גדול מהם בחכמה רבו או אביו שהוא תלמיד חכם קודם לזה שהוא
>   גדול ממנו:

If one has before him many poor people and he does not have a enough money to support them or to cover them or to redeem them one should place precedence according to his tribeand lineage a Kohen comes before a Levi and Levi before a Yisroel... When do we say this? Only when they are all equal in wisdom, however if one is greater in wisdom despite the fact that he is of a lower status of tribe, since he has more wisdom he has precedence and thus you should give him the Tzedaka first.

In general, despite the The obligation to give charity to those who ask and one mustn't delve too deeply whether or not someone is a liar or is misrepresenting himself. Nonetheless, we see in the Gemara Kesuvos 68a:

> היינו דאמר רבי אלעזר בואו ונחזיק טובה לרמאין שאלמלא הן היינו חוטאין
>   בכל יום שנאמר {דברים טו-ט} וקרא עליך אל ה' והיה בך חטא

Rabbi Eliezer says "let us find some good attribute of liars for if it were not for them we would be sinning every day.

Rashi explains Rabbi Eliezer  statement: "because by closing our eyes from the poor we would be sinning everyday, but now with all the liars out there we are forced to"

From this passage of Gemara  we see that nowadays there is no obligation to give money to just anyone who asks, especially if many of the panhandlers are known to be liars.

However see the the Rambam (מתנות עניים ז:ז):

> מפרנסין ומכסין עניי עכו''ם עם עניי ישראל מפני דרכי שלום. **ועני המחזר
>   על הפתחים אין נזקקין לו למתנה מרובה אבל נותנין לו מתנה מועטת. ואסור
>   להחזיר את העני ששאל ריקם ואפילו אתה נותן לו גרוגרת אחת שנאמר אל ישוב
>   דך נכלם:**

You must give the panhandler something, for it is forbidden to leave them empty handed

So although you are not obligated to give money, nonetheless you should give them something, whether that be food or a drink of some sort. And maybe a small amount of money.

In your case where many beggers solicit you, the best thing is to give them something, even a small amount.

Comment: For a contemporary story about lying beggars, see [The Man with the Twisted Lip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_with_the_Twisted_Lip), a Sherlock Holmes story.