# A hungry beggar asks to use your credit card to buy food. Must you give it?

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity

[This M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16837/5275) states that if a beggar asks you for food, you do not investigate, but provide food. I assume that if you give cash so that the beggar can buy food, that is the same.

A few months ago, while I was shopping in my local market, a woman said she was hungry and asked if she could borrow my credit card so that she could buy food. I was astounded, as I never had this proposal before. I refused but gave her a few dollars.

2 concerns at the time:

1 - I was also very concerned about the security risk of her taking my account info or not even returning my card, itself. I'd like to be able to help a hungry person, but, do I need to implicitly trust in G-d and her that she won't abuse my credit card?

2A - She would probably spend far more than I can afford. Wouldn't it be more embarrassing to her if I held onto my card and then when she checked out I say, "Well, I can only pay this much?"

2B - I could tell the beggar in advance how much I can afford, and rely on her to buy only that amount. What if she says that would still leave her hungry?

2C - What if I don't have the time to wait for the beggar to shop for her items, and I don't have the time to buy them?

Is there any requirement under such circumstances to offer a credit card?

Incidentally, when I initially offered the cash, the woman refused and **insisted** on using my card. Only after I told her that there was no way I would do that, and she should take my money, did she accept the money!

Comment: is the assumption in your question that credit card is different than actual money?

Comment: @Mefaresh For this question, yes, it is different. If I gave her cash, there are no security concerns.

Comment: I've unfortunately had a similar instance of chutzpah, where what I thought was going to be a minor transaction done as a favor ended up as a major imposition. I normally say "I'll buy you some food" when people ask for money, but no WAY would I give them free reign. A lunch is reasonable, grocery shopping isn't. ***Regardless, asking for a credit card to buy food is NOT the same thing as asking for food.***

Comment: but that isnt a tzedaka question. That is a security question.

Comment: @Mefaresh a bit of both. I don't have a security concern if I paid for her at checkout as I woyuld be holding onto the card. But, she would end up buying an unknown quantity of food which I probably couldn't afford. That's a tzedaka / monetary question.

Comment: maybe you should clarify these points, otherwise interesting question ;-)

Comment: I believe Rabbi Schechter of YU is quoted as having ruled that it's *assur* to be stupid.

Comment: @DanF. As an observation, I think your question whether or not you should have loaned a beggar your credit card is a beautiful reflection of your Jewish neshama.

Comment: If a beggar asks you to lend him your car are you required to give it? If a beggar asks you for $100 are you required to give it? I am sure the answer to these questions and to yours is a resounding no. For that matter does one have to go into debt to give charity?

Comment: @JJLL I appreciate the compliment. But, seriously, in this case, I was really not so generous, b/c I was shocked by the request, and the chutzpa to ask me for my card after I offered the cash and the person refused and insisted on the card! Sometimes I ask questions just b/c I'm curious what the answer would be, as is the case, here.

Comment: @Loewian That's an interesting quote, but, I'd be somewhat surprised if esp. he, being from YU would phrase it this way. I have a bias towards any YU-affiliated rav who has been there a long time as he has, since I believe he went along with relinquishing the proposed YU anti-smoking ban, that they relinquished b/c of peer pressure. Not supporting the ban, is, in a sense, allowing people to be stupid.