# To whom should one's Maaser be given first, a Kolel or poor people?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

Are those learning in the kolel considered poor? They are able (at least where I'm from) to make a pretty decent living, with the Kolel's salary and support from their families.

Is it more important to help those in a more desperate financial situation?

Comment: "and support from their families" Meaning, someone is already giving them charity.

Comment: Why would you think to give money to someone who has a job (and can probably get a better one) over someone in "a more desperate financial situation"?

Comment: @doubleAA Because you could see the kolel as an institution, rather than a group of individual abrechim. it needs donations to stay functional as a place where people learn.  Does that make sense? Also the support from the families is an inaccurate generalization, although it tends to be the most common case.

Comment: You mean you'd be donating towards the existence of a communal institution which provides services to the community? That's a whole different discussion. Now you're asking about supporting communal infrastructure vs individual poor people. Nothing to do with if the Kollel learners are considered poor or not, or Kollel at all (could be Mikvah, butcher, etc.). From your question it is not at all clear that this Kollel is serves a communal function as opposed to just random people learning for themselves.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes I guess that would be the main point of my question, because if you give money to the kolel, it might as well be used to buy coffee as to pay an abrech's salary. sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I'm closing this as unclear because you've mentioned in the comments what you really mean, and that meaning isn't in the question post. Once it's edited in, the question can certainly be reopened. Comments are ephemeral by design, and one can't expect a question's readers to read the comments even while the comments are extant.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11980